# Remove / Edit splash screen on Android

Tags: android, delphi

I am using RAD Studio 10.1.
I would like to disable / edit the properties of the default splash screen? 
I tried to remove it from the project options but it generates errors.

[image: Delphi RAD Studio 10.1 default Android app splash screen]

Comment: Just replace all the images with your own images with the same sizes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your own just replace the default images with your own images with the same sizes like below :

[image]

If you want a blanck one just add a white image.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if you don't want an image at all then uncheck Include Splash.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30020588)